# "Screen-Reader tool Orca" and extendable/customizable functionality in Ubuntu?

Tags: text-to-speech, orca, speech-recognition

**Here is what i want to do:**

1. I want to put/run [Orca](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/Orca?action=show&redirect=Orca) as an idle process in background after booting into Ubuntu. (No problem there so far.)
2. Now when I open up a text file or website in my [web]browser; I want to be able, to highlight text and use a keyboard-shortcut in order to invoke Orca process [see step 1], to read the selected text back to me.

My problem is, that Orca, once initialized as a running process permanently reads back everything, from mouse-over actions of buttons, to system related actions etc.. and orca-preferences doesn't come with options, to reduce and suppress this. Orca might not be the right application at all for this and a common speech-synthesis application might be even better.

- If someone knows how to make it work that way, please help.
- An alternative speech-synthesis "read back" option/function, like Apple offers in OS X would even be better, since there one can simply "selected text", that is invoked with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>#</kbd> shortcut, or simply use `say`, or for text files `say -f ~/input.txt -o ~/output.aiff`-command to have text red back instantly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/09/linux-text-to-speech-with-festival/), in this comment, which does the trick in combination with festival:
(Although, these "free" speech synthesis are not even close to be as good as they ought to be!!)

---

**wizo chocs says:** March 2, 2012 at 12:49 pm

create this script xtalk

```
#!/bin/bash
xsel | festival --tts --pipe
```

- set it executable `chmod 755 xtalk`
- create a new custom keyboard shortcut, any key combo, i use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> and the
  prog to run is your xtalk script
- select the text u want read press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: This is working so far. But needs xsel to be installed in order to work. Don't forget the double dash on the festival parameters.

Comment: I found that xsel needs the option -o, otherwise it just hangs

Answer (score 1):

Would Festival do what you want? http://www.ghacks.net/2010/10/09/linux-text-to-speech-with-festival/

You also have http://clickspeak.clcworld.net/index.html or http://www.firevox.clcworld.net/installation_linux.html wich is a plugin for firefox

Comment: +1 for the links and thank you. The first link is interesting, yet i prefer the key-shortcut option to activate text to speech, rather than bash.

Answer (score 1):

Based on v2r's answer I made this script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ID=$(pgrep -x "espeak")
if $ID >/dev/null 2>&1
  then
    xsel | espeak -vmb-en1
  else
    kill $ID
fi
```

This script will stop reading when you push the key combo a second time while it is reading.

I installed

```
 espeak
 espeak-ng-espeak
 xsel
 mbrola
```

and the some mbrola voices :

```
mbrola-de1
mbrola-de2
mbrola-de3
mbrola-de4
mbrola-de5
mbrola-de6
mbrola-de7
mbrola-en1
mbrola-sw1
mbrola-sw2
mbrola-us1
mbrola-us2
mbrola-us3
```

I made a separate script and key combo for every language.
like `Pause` for English and `Shift + Pause` for German.

I use Ubuntu 18.04

For Firefox I would recommend the Talkie extension. It reads very fine and automatically detects languages.

Comment: Great! Thank you - definitely give it a go later.